# Compare one to one lines in 2 different files using shell scripting

Tags: shell, diff, string-comparison, cut

I have 2 files:

File1 --------------------------------------->File2

abc -----------------------------------------> abc
cde -----------------------------------------> cde,xyz,efg,hij,...,n

efg -----------------------------------------> lmn,opq,weq,...n

Now I want to File1 line1 -> File2 line1, line 2 -> line2 and so on...
However, in file2 a single line can have multiple entries separated with 'comma'.

now if the entry in file1 matches with the any of the corresponding line entry in file 2 -> result ok
Else show the diff...

For example:

FILE1 ----------------------  FILE2

cde   ----------------------   cde,xyz,efg,hij,opt

the result should be ok because cde exist in both files.

Can you please help me out to write a shell script for the same
sdiff gave me the entries difference also

Answer (score 0):

Consider these two test files:

```
$ cat file1
abc
cde
efg

$ cat file2
abc
cde,xyz,efg,hij,n
lmn,opq,weq,n
```

Consider the command:

```
$ awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$1;next} {f=0;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i==a[FNR])f=1;if(f)print "OK";else print a[FNR]" -----> " $0}' file1 file2
OK
OK
efg -----> lmn,opq,weq,n
```

This prints `OK` on every line for which the key in `file1` is found anywhere on the corresponding line in `file2`.  If it is not, it prints both lines as shown.

#### Another example

From the comments, consider these two files in which all lines have a match:

```
$ cat f1
abc
cde
mno

$ cat f2
abc
efg,cde,hkl
mno

$ awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$1;next} {f=0;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i==a[FNR])f=1;if(f)print "OK";else print a[FNR]" -----> " $0}' f1 f2
OK
OK
OK
```

Comment: Thanks John, I'm getting a different Output.. its printing both files with null. Can you please help me out on this

bash-3.2# cat file1.txt 

abc

cde

mno

bash-3.2# cat file2.txt 

abc

efg,cde,hkl

mno

bash-3.2# 

bash-3.2# awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$1;next} {f=0;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i==a[FNR])f=1;if(f)print "OK";else print a[FNR]" -----> " $0}' file1.txt file2.txt

 -----> abc

 -----> cde

 -----> mno

 -----> abc

 -----> efg,cde,hkl

 -----> mno

Comment: @KaranKohli  What do you means by "its printing both files with null"?  I added the output that I get to the answer. Also, if you are on bash-3.2, that means that you using OSX?  If so, that also means that you using the BSD utilities, including BSD `awk`.  My command was tested under GNU `awk` but I also tested it with the `--posix` option to verify that it should work under any standard compliant `awk`.  Since I do not have access to a Mac to test under BSD directly, you will need to be very very clear about what you do and what messages the commands emit.